# Increasing Search Performance by Splitting Index

Tags: elasticsearch

Please bear with me as I am a novice with Elasticsearch so I may not have all the terminology completely correct and I am still working on understanding the basic concepts and architecture.

We have an Elasticsearch cluster that contains a monolithic index.  In the index, we have it configured so that we have 35 primary and 35 replica shards (1:1). Due to the increase of expected data that we will be indexing,(we currently index about 1 million documents per day and it may increase 10 fold), we are thinking of splitting the index into multiple indices based upon months or quarters.  The documents that are indexed have the ability to be updated, however most documents probably won't be indexed after a year's time.  All data will be retained and searchable for at least 5 years.

My question is whether this seems like a reasonable option in terms of scaling and offering better search performance?  Or can performance be increased, by adding more nodes to the cluster even if it becomes a huge monolithic cluster?

Thanks for any insight that may be provided.

Comment: Sorry meant to say that most documents won't be searched after a year, however, they must  be available for search for at least 5 years and actually maybe occasionally 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's better to avoid having a monolithic index and break the index into smaller chunks. This will allow you to decrease the shards for the older indices (where the queries might be low) and free up resources for the current (hot) indices. Make sure you are keeping the shard size around the recommended size of 10 to 20 GB's.

You can then also explore hot-warm architecture solutions to reduce the overall cost.